# Cambiar código en varias paginas a la vez ATOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como puedo hacer que un trozo de código en ATOM sea una especie de plantilla que, al cambiar algo en uno de los archivos, se cambie automáticamente en todos.

Ejemplo:

```css
footer{
  background-color: #273B47;
  color: white;
}
h4, p {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h4>Hola esto es un texto de prueba</h4>
  <p>Esto es un parrafo de prueba que va a estar en todas las páginas de mi sitio</p>
</footer>
```

Me gustaría que si hago un cambio en el texto de mi footer, se cambiase también en todas las paginas donde esté ese texto por el nuevo.

No se si habrá algún Addon para ATOM que permita esto, y no tener que ir cambiando página por página si quiero hacer un cambio en una parte de mi código que va a estar en todas las páginas de mi sitio.

Comment: Hola amigo, podrías publicarnos un fragmento de tu estructura.

Comment: Por favor agrega un [mcve] que muestre qué problema real y concreto enfrentas al tratar de lograr tu objetivo. El código que publicas no tiene ningún problema, así que tu pregunta podría ser cerrada porque el supuesto problema no se puede reproducir. Si buscas ideas, opiniones o sugerencias, usa Google. Si quieres que te entreguen el código listo y funcionando, la pregunta se debe cerrar por ser demasiado amplia. Puedes editar tu pregunta en el siguiente enlace: __[edit]__.

Comment: Si el mismo código aparece en muchos de tus ficheros, hay un problema de diseño. Deberías reconsiderar lo que estás haciendo y cómo.

Answer (score 0):

Pues tu lo que buscas es un creador de Snippets, hay varios plugins en Brakets, en Atom realmente no conozco, pero supongo que puedes buscarlo en google como "Snippet Perzonalizador Atom"